# Flutter find the sum of digits of int value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to find the sum of the digits of the number entered in Flutter. I want to encode this algorithm.

for example
x=1992
result=1+9+9+2=21

how can i do this with flutter

Comment: Flutter use dart, so you can calculate creating a simple method where split the number and sum from the array created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this way.

```
import 'dart:io';
 
void main() {
  print('Enter X');
  int X = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
 
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = X; i > 0; i = (i / 10).floor()) {
    result += (i % 10);
  }
 
  print('Sum of digits\n$result');
}
```

`Output`

Enter X
123456
Sum of digits
21

Answer (score 1):

1. transform the number into an String using `String stringValue = x.toString();`
2. create an array from each char using `List<String> result = stringValue.split('');`
3. sum each number transforming back using `int.parse(result)`

```dart
void main(){
  int x = 1992;
  String stringValue = x.toString();
  List<String> result = stringValue.split('');
  int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < result.length; i++) {
    int value = int.parse(result[i]);
    sum = sum + value;
   }
    print(sum);
}
```

Result: 21